# Generic call a method in different classes, but with the same method signature

Tags: java, generics

Say there are two classes `Foo` and `Bar`. They don't extend the same class (except for the `Object` class) or implement the same interface. However, both of them have a method with the same signature. These classes are not mine; they cannot be changed. Is there a way to use some kind of generic call for method `meth` as if these two classes extended the same class or implemented the same interface?

```
class Foo {

    public void meth(String s) {
    }
}

class Bar {

    public void meth(String s) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection, but not type safe. depending on Object run time you can call specific method.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method; 

try 
    {
        Object f1 = new Foo();
        Object f2 = new Bar();

        Class c1 = f1.getClass();
        Class[] param = new Class[1];   
        param[0] = String.class;
        Method method;
        method = c1.getDeclaredMethod("meth", param);
        method.invoke(f1, "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");

    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 or later you can use method references.

```
Foo myFoo = ...;
Bar myBar = ...;

Consumer<String> fn1 = myFoo::meth;
Consumer<String> fn2 = myBar::meth;
```

Pass the appropriate `Consumer<String>` to the place where you want the method called.

`Consumer<String>` is appropriate for a method with one string argument and no return type. If your method signatures were different, there are lots of other functional interfaces that might match better.

Given a `Consumer<String> fn`, you can call the referenced method with [`fn.accept("abc")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html#accept-T-).

Comment: The methods take one argument and return void. Could you describe how to handle this situation, please?

Comment: @menteith OK. I've altered my answer.